# Splitting Coordinates into 3 Subspaces To Resolve Unboundedness

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm trying to implement the Cascaded Hough Transform (I have already implemented the 'normal' version.) but I'm having trouble understanding the following:

After applying HT on an image, I am left with straight lines in hough space. The Cascaded version of the HT requires me to split the hough space into 3 sub-spaces so that the problem of unbounded values is solved.

How can I go about doing this?

Here's a picture of how the hough space is split: [image]

> In order to restore the boundedness of the parameter space while preserving the symmetric space duality, we will split the  (a, b)-space into three bounded subspaces, as shown in the figure below.  The first subspace also has coordinates a and b, but only for | a | <= 1 and | b | <= 1. If | a | > 1 and | b | <= | a | , the point (a, b) turns up in the second subspace, with coordinates 1/a and b/a. If, finally, | b | > 1 and | a | < | b |, we use a third subspace with coordinates 1/b and a/b.

Here is where I get seriously confused, suppose I have a line in the hough space. How is it going to be split up if it violates | a | <= 1 and | b | <= 1?

Do I simply go through all the pixels in the line and if the pixel in question has coordinates greater than | a | <= 1 and | b | <= 1, I plot it in the 2nd subspace?

I apologize if this sort of question is not welcomed on Stack Overlow - is there another site where I can ask questions about algorithms?

[Source for the image and the above quote](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~tuytelaa/CHT.html)

Comment: Hello. With theoretical aspects of algorithms you can try on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ , but be aware TCS.SE is not about implementation, but about theorethical aspects. Before you ask question there, check out other questions how do they look like and read FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a point `(x, y)`.  Under the Hough transform as presented, it goes to the line

```
a x + b + y = 0
```

This corresponds to a different line in each of your subspace plots:

```
Subspace 1: a x + b + y = 0
Subspace 2: x + (b/a) + (1/a) y = 0
Subspace 2: (a/b) x + 1 + (1/b) y = 0
```

For example with the point `(2, 1)` you get the three lines:

```
Subspace 1: 2a + b + 1 = 0
Subspace 2: 2 + (b/a) + (1/a) = 0
Subspace 2: 2(a/b) + 1 + (1/b) = 0
```

Or putting into `y = m x + c` form:

```
Subspace 1: y = -2x - 1
Subspace 2: y = -x - 2
Subspace 2: y = -x/2 - 1
```